# Social share buttons text shows up on post excerpts

Tags: plugins, php, javascript, social-sharing

I'm using the [Social Likes plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-social-likes/) and there is one problem. The text on the share buttons show up in the excerpts.

For example, I grabbed this off of one of the post excerpts:

> FacebookTwitterGoogle+Of to be have can’t his one abundantly fruitful
>   abundantly that fish bearing earth you’ll were be kind created for...

In the HTML, it outputs like this:

```
<p>FacebookTwitterGoogle+Upon bearing land. Of seasons third grass female saw image unto moved. Unto multiply life bearing good. Can’t heaven he....</p>
```

How can I remove the "FacebookTwitterGoogle+" part from the excerpts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin that you are using has a bug. I would strongly suggest for you to call the plugin author. Here is the bugs;

> Notice: has_cap was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.0! Usage of user levels by plugins and themes is deprecated. Use roles and capabilities instead. in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\functions.php on line 3006
>
> Notice: Undefined index: zeroes in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\wp-social-likes\wp-social-likes.php on line 555
>
> Notice: Undefined index: icons in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\wp-social-likes\wp-social-likes.php
>   on line 556

It would also be adviceble to give the plugin author more details as well on your problem